# Why isn't uploadify and asp.net mvc 2 playing nice for me?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

First of all, I've checked out all the SO threads, and googled my brains out. I must be missing something obvious. 
I'd really appreciate some help! This is what I've got.

**UploadController.cs**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NIMDocs.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public string Processed(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
        {
            // DO STUFF

            return "DUHR I AM SMART";
        }

    }
}
```

**Index for Upload**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>ITS A TITLE </title>
    <script src="../../Content/jqueryPlugins/uploadify/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/jqueryPlugins/uploadify/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/jqueryPlugins/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#uploadify').fileUpload({
            'uploader': '../../Content/jqueryPlugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/Upload/Processed',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'multi': 'true',
            'buttonText': 'Browse',
            'displayData': 'speed',
            'simUploadLimit': 2,
            'cancelImg': '/Content/Images/cancel.png'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />
<p><a href="javascript:jQuery('#uploadify').uploadifyClearQueue()">Cancel All Uploads</a></p>
</body>

    </html>
```

What am I missing here? I've tried just about every path permutation for uploadify's "uploader" option. Absolute path, '/' prefixed, etc.

This is what I'm seeing. 
[image]

And here is the directory structure. 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spelt Processed *Procssed* and therefore you will not hit *'script': '/Upload/Processed',*

Change

```
public string Procssed(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
{
        // DO STUFF
        return "DUHR I AM SMART";
}
```

to

```
public string Processed(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
{
        // DO STUFF
        return "O SMART ONE HAS SPOKEN";
}
```

***EDIT***

Remove your jquery script code block and your html input and use this code instead

```
<body>
<input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader': '../../Content/jqueryPlugins/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/Upload/Processed',
            'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
            'auto': true,
            'folder': '/uploads'
        });
    });
// ]]>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Good catch, but I'm still not having any luck. I've added some edits that may help to my original post.

Thanks

Comment: Try the edit above - works fine for me (can see the uploaded file in newFile)
public string Processed(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase newFile = FileData;
            return "DUHR I AM SMART";
        }

Comment: Awesome. What exactly was i doing wrong? The trailing ]]> ? I cannot thank you enough. I do have another quick question for you if you don't mind... is uploadify actually uploading the document to /uploads? If so, where is it on the local directory?

Comment: public string Processed(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase newFile = FileData;
            FileData.SaveAs(@"c:\Temp\" + FileData.FileName);
            return "File Saved";
        }
or you could use in conjunction with something like var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("folders");

Answer (score 2):

Your spelling of "Processed" varies between the javascript call (`Processed`) and the method definition (`Procssed`). Is that incidental?

Comment: yes actually that is incidental. I've changed the controller names so many times that one got past me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but in classic ASP ASP.net webforms, the form enctype  had to be set to 
multipart/form-data

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='file'>
 <input type='Submit'>
</form>
```